# Criar pasta em .bat com nome de acordo com a data e dia da semana atual

Tags: cmd, batch, automatização, backup, bat

Estou tentado realizar um backup diário de uma pasta via código .bat + o ***Task Schedule*** mas parece que o código funciona vez sim e vez não informando que "0 arquivos foram copiados"

Saberiam dizer o que está errado ?
A ideia é copiar uma pasta inteira, logo realizar uma cópia em outro local e alterar o nome da pasta com a data atual. *Exemplo: Hoje é dia 10/03/2022 então a pasta se chamaria "backup_10_03_2022_Quinta"*

[image: Mensagem final]

```
@echo off & @setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_dias_=0-Domingo,1-Segunda,2-Terca,3-Quarta,4-Quinta,5-Sexta,6-Sabado"

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims= " %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year^,DayOfWeek^| findstr /r "[0-9]"') do (
    if not %%a geq 10 (set "_data=0%%a") else (set "_data=%%~a")
    if not %%c geq 10 (set "_data=!_data: =!0%%c") else (set "_data=!_data: =!%%~c")
    set "_data=!_data!%%d" & set "DayOfWeek=%%b"
    )
for %%d in (!_dias_!)do for /F %%D in ('echo/!DayOfWeek!') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2delims=-" %%1 in ('echo/%%d') do if "%%D" equ "%%1" set "_data=!_data!_%%2"&&goto :_next_:
    )

:_next_:
set _backup_file=backup_!_data!
echo ++++++++++Iniciando Backup+++++++++++++++
echo.
xcopy /D /E /C /K /O /S /Y /I /H "C:\Temp\Teste" "C:\Temp\backup_!_data!\" 
echo ++++++++++++Fim+++++++++++
pause
```

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/544923/criar-pasta-e-utilizar-a-data-atual-no-nome-batch - Pode clicar no link e editar sua pergunta original conforme orientações do link do quadro de fechamento, que se a comunidade entender que atende aos requisitos, pode votar para reabrir. Vou deixar alguns links extra no campo de comentários de lá, que talvez ajudem na edição, e bloquear os comentários daqui para evitar informação perdida em 2 postagens de mesmo teor (se alguem precisar, na original o campo de comentários continua funcional).